# Huge Delay in receiving Chrome Extension Updates

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I release chrome extension updates on a regular basis. It has been observed that we have a lot of machines running old versions of extension even days after the update.

I tried logging the version number on update for our users. Following are the stats from the day of giving the update.

```
Days since update | % of users updated on that day

0                      34
1                      28
2                      12
3                      7
4                      3
5                      3
6                      1.7
7                      1.2
```

The extension is published using google developer dashboard .I requested no additional permissions since the last version.

I have the following queries.

Is this normal?

Google says that the apps/extensions get autoupdated within an hour of releasing update once the browser is closed/restarted.
Does it mean 40% of my users don't even restart chrome in 2 days?

Is there a way to force an update into all machines on the same day itself ?

Comment: I have gone weeks without closing / restarting Chrome - there's very rarely a reason for me to.

Comment: Well most of the users are on Windows, where chrome would get exited on closing unlike OSX. 40% of users not exiting chrome even 2 days later seems surprising to me.

Comment: closing all tabs isnt exiting. you have to do menu+exit afaik. also, chrome does update extensions even while running.

Comment: Last I checked on Windows if you have background extensions closing all tabs will not exit, if you do not have background extensions closing all tabs will exit.

Comment: That being said, yes, it pretty expected for there to be a long tail of updates. Some users will only turn their computer on once a week, they have firewalls blocking downloads, etc. If having users on the current version is critical to your app have a look at [chrome.runtime.requestUpdateCheck](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#method-requestUpdateCheck).